# Fire a file input click programmatically in vanilla js via ajax (chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome

I've got a webapp in which any button click sends an ajax request to the server, the server validates and sends js code back to the client. The framework i am using is disallowing me to implement jQuery (it causes unpredictable problems).

My problem is, that i have a button, that should open a file picker when clicked. And it already works in firefox and ie. To achieve this i set up a hidden file input:

```
<input type="file" style="z-index: 999999999; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
```

Now, when i click the button this is what happens:

1. A ajax request is send to the server, notifying it, that the button was clicked.
2. The server knows the dynamically created IDs of the html elements, finds the right ones and answer this to the client:

   `dropzone_[ID].inputClick();`

([ID] is the dynamically created ID, that only my server knows for sure)

3. Then, the method "inputClick()" is called on the client and performs the click on the hidden input field. The code looks like this:

   dropzone.hiddenFileInput.focus();
   dropzone.hiddenFileInput.click();
4. Finally the file picker shows up, and i can select files properly.

It seems to be a security issue in chrome to make it work like this. And I've already seen a lot of other people with a similar problem where focusing the input field helped, but that did not apply here.
Also firefox and ie seem to understand that the click is a legit, delegated click via ajax, but chrome does not.

The server communication itself has no problem. An added `console.log()` to the `inputClick()` method will always fire, on all browser, but the click event is not fired in chrome.

Has anyone an idea how to write a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
el = dropzone.hiddenFileInput;
if (el.onclick) {
   el.onclick();
} else if (el.click) {
   el.click();
}
```

Some browsers uses `onclick()`. It's because of this people uses frameworks and libraries as jQuery, Mootools, etc, to avoid crossbrowser issues. I don't know why your framework doesn't allows jQuery because *unpredictable issues*, this means that your framework is wrong-coded because jQuery runs perfectly in all browsers.

### EDIT

I think that you are experimenting a bug in chrome. Please, test this code:

```
   if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
         var fireOnThis = document.getElementById('element');
         var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
         evObj.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null );
         fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
         return true;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try it now.
And the problem with the framework is, that the html is created fully via js. It can happen, that jquery is implemented at the wrong moment.

This did not fix the issue. I once tried it without ajax and a eventListener and it worked in chrome. The prolems occures when using ajax to fire the event

Comment: If `onclick` doesn't works for you, maybe you need to try a dispatcher. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: I already tried this, too. It can only be a security issue. Chrome prevents all tries to fire a click event on file inputs, if the click was not initially created by the user. So only if a user actually clicks, the click event can be delegated/fired on the input field. The main problem is that, through the ajax call, chrome seems not to understand that the click was initially created by the user. But there must be a way for this :/

Also, yep the framework sucks - was not my idea

Comment: I think in a bug instead of security reasons. Chrome is full of bugs, specially in CSS and Javascript behaviour, because his own particularities.

Comment: I just tried the code. BrowserDetect caused a reference error, so i replaced it with: `!!window.chrome`. But still, dispatching a new event does not work for chrome.
I just found the workaround, that i create a usual eventlistener from the server side. Problem with this is, that all HTML code is generated by the framwork and i am black-box editing it. The framework is not supposed to work this way. This means that it may work now, but with the next update may break again. I will contact google to fix it since it works in other browsers. Anyway thanks for your help:)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry that I cannot help you better. I'm sure that's a bug. If you search in google, chrome has bugs like this (related with event dispatching) since 2009 and still not solved the big part. Came here if you need another ideas to reach the goal. Good luck!